# using <hr/> after each group of records

Tags: php

hi i have a search result form, i have a problem, i do not know how to use a line of <.hr/> after each group of records.
as you see result of next user is near previous one.

> here is my code:

```
.
.
.
<?php

$firstname = '';
$oldfirst = '';

$lastname = '';
$oldlast = '';

$phone_number = '';
$oldphone_number = '';

$positive = '';
$oldpositive = '';

$negative = '';
$oldnegative = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    if($oldfirst == $row['name'] &&
       $oldlast == $row['family'] &&
       $oldphone_number == $row['phone_number'] &&
       $oldpositive == $row['positive'] &&
       $oldnegative == $row['negative'])
    {
        $firstname = ' ';
        $lastname = ' ';
        $phone_number = ' ';
        $positive = ' ';
        $negative = ' ';
        /***************/
        $namelabel = ' ';
        $phone_numberlabel= ' ';
        $positivelabel = ' ';
        $negativelabel = ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        $firstname = $row['name'];
        $lastname = $row['family'];
        $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
        $positive = $row['positive'];
        $negative = $row['negative'];
        /*********************/
        $namelabel = 'نام: ';
        $phone_numberlabel= 'شماره تلفن: ';
        $positivelabel = 'عملیات های موفق: ';
        $negativelabel = 'عملیات نا موفق: ';
    }

    $oldfirst = $row['name'];
    $oldlast = $row['family'];
    $oldphone_number = $row['phone_number'];
    $oldpositive = $row['positive'];
    $oldnegative = $row['negative'];


printf("{$namelabel} %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {$phone_numberlabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

        {$positivelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {$negativelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <br/>
        شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        توضیحات: %s",
        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $phone_number,
        $positive,
        $negative,
        $row["job_name"], 
        $row["comments"]);
    }
?>
```

where to put <.hr/> to divide results?

> here is result of code:

[image]

> some guys made this, its not true and is not for each group of information. additionally makes a empty line:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first note that the line is gonne be horizontal, you can't break it. Then, it can be placed anywhere between double quotations "". Oh and it doesn't have dot -> `<hr/>`

```
printf("{$namelabel} %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {$phone_numberlabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

        {$positivelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {$negativelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <br/>
        شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        توضیحات: %s <hr/>",
        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $phone_number,
        $positive,
        $negative,
        $row["job_name"], 
        $row["comments"]);
    }
```

EDITED:

```
if($oldfirst == $row['name'] &&
   $oldlast == $row['family'] &&
   $oldphone_number == $row['phone_number'] &&
   $oldpositive == $row['positive'] &&
   $oldnegative == $row['negative'])
{
    $firstname = ' ';
    $lastname = ' ';
    $phone_number = ' ';
    $positive = ' ';
    $negative = ' ';
    /***************/
    $hr = '';
    $namelabel = ' ';
    $phone_numberlabel= ' ';
    $positivelabel = ' ';
    $negativelabel = ' ';
}
else
{
    $firstname = $row['name'];
    $lastname = $row['family'];
    $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
    $positive = $row['positive'];
    $negative = $row['negative'];
    /*********************/
    $hr = '<hr/>';
    $namelabel = 'نام: ';
    $phone_numberlabel= 'شماره تلفن: ';
    $positivelabel = 'عملیات های موفق: ';
    $negativelabel = 'عملیات نا موفق: ';
}
```

Then

```
echo $hr;
printf("{$namelabel} %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {$phone_numberlabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

        {$positivelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {$negativelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <br/>
        شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        توضیحات: %s",
        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $phone_number,
        $positive,
        $negative,
        $row["job_name"], 
        $row["comments"]);
    }
```

Comment: this make <hr/> after each 'توضیحات'. i want hr after each group of details!

Comment: i put a picture of your tries end of my question. its wrong

Comment: forget about the first thing that I posted. Use the edited version which is simple modifications of your code. The if/else and the printf part. I've just added an $hr variable which takes it's value from your condition

Comment: unexpected T_STRING here: printf("{$hr}{$namelabel} %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

Comment: what about now? Guess %s messed with the $hr.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95348/discussion-between-sajad-and-sinazza).

Comment: hi, can you help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776286/how-to-check-if-a-field-is-not-unique?noredirect=1#comment55319477_33776286

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will solve your problem.

```
<?php

$firstname = '';
$oldfirst = '';

$lastname = '';
$oldlast = '';

$phone_number = '';
$oldphone_number = '';

$positive = '';
$oldpositive = '';

$negative = '';
$oldnegative = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    if($oldfirst == $row['name'] &&
       $oldlast == $row['family'] &&
       $oldphone_number == $row['phone_number'] &&
       $oldpositive == $row['positive'] &&
       $oldnegative == $row['negative'])
    {
        $firstname = ' ';
        $lastname = ' ';
        $phone_number = ' ';
        $positive = ' ';
        $negative = ' ';
        /***************/
        $namelabel = ' ';
        $phone_numberlabel= ' ';
        $positivelabel = ' ';
        $negativelabel = ' ';
        $hr=""; // add $hr variable and set value null for repeating records
    }
    else
    {
        $firstname = $row['name'];
        $lastname = $row['family'];
        $phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
        $positive = $row['positive'];
        $negative = $row['negative'];
        /*********************/
        $namelabel = 'نام: ';
        $phone_numberlabel= 'شماره تلفن: ';
        $positivelabel = 'عملیات های موفق: ';
        $negativelabel = 'عملیات نا موفق: ';
        $hr="<hr/>"; // add $hr variable and set value <hr/> for unique records
    }

    $oldfirst = $row['name'];
    $oldlast = $row['family'];
    $oldphone_number = $row['phone_number'];
    $oldpositive = $row['positive'];
    $oldnegative = $row['negative'];


printf("{$namelabel} %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {$phone_numberlabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

        {$positivelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        {$negativelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <br/>
        شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        توضیحات: %s",
        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $phone_number,
        $positive,
        $negative,
        $row["job_name"], 
        $row["comments"]);
        echo $hr; // echo <hr/> here
    }
?>
```

Comment: shouldn't the <hr/> tag go before the closing curly bracket? Since he want's it after every group.

Comment: Yes it will be before curly bracket. i have updated.

Comment: no it make hr after each 'توضیحات'. not true. i want hr after each group my information that belongs to each user

Comment: i put a picture of your tries end of my question. its wrong

Answer (score 0):

after `printf` as follows.

```
printf("{$namelabel} %s %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp {$phone_numberlabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp {$positivelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp {$negativelabel} %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <br/> شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp توضیحات: %s", $firstname, $lastname, $phone_number, $positive, $negative, $row["job_name"], $row["comments"]); 
echo '<hr/>';
```