# no working disabling textfield when records are more than one

Tags: javascript, php

in this code, while opening page, text fields would be disabled. user can enable or disable text field with check box. unfortunately when results are more than one, disabling do not works, but when there is just one record, disabling and enabling works. where is the problem?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function enable_text(status)
{
status=!status; 
    document.f1.explain.disabled = status;
}
//-->
</script>


  <?php
$id=$fgmembersite->UserID(); 
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'action';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");

$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT tablesite.name,
                              tablesite.family,
                              tablesite.username,
                              tablesite.phone_number,
                              tablesite.email,
                              action.service_provider_comment,
                              action.price,
                              action.date,
                              job_list.job_name,
                              action.ind
                       FROM  $db_table
                       INNER JOIN job_list
                       on job_list.job_id=action.job_id 
                       INNER JOIN tablesite
                       on tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id AND action.customer_id='$id'
                       WHERE vote=''",$con);
   $i = 1;

                       while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))

{


echo "<form name=f1 id='form_$i' method='post' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}' accept-charset='UTF-8'>\r\n";
echo'<div dir="rtl">';
echo "نام خدمت دهنده: "."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp".$amch["name"]." ".$amch["family"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."شماره تماس: ".$amch["phone_number"]."&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"."ایمیل: ".$amch["email"].'<br>'.

"شغل انجام شده: ".$amch["job_name"].'<br>'
."تاریخ انجام عملیات: ".$amch["date"].'<br>'
."هزینه ی کار: ".$amch["price"]." تومان".'<br>'
.$amch["service_provider_comment"].'<hr/>';
/*echo'<label for=\'body\'>توضیحات: </label> <br />';*/
    echo'<label for="explain" style="color:#CC0000">این فیلد را فقط در صورتی پر کنید که شکایت دارید</label> <br />';
    echo'<input type="checkbox" name=others onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" >شکایت دارم <br>';
    echo'<textarea name="explain" id="explain" cols="" rows="" style="width:300 ;height:300">
    </textarea>'.'<br/>'; 

echo'<label for="vote">امتیاز این عملیات را ثبت نمایید: </label> <br />';
echo '<select name="vote">';
echo '<option value="عالی">عالی</option>';
echo '<option value="خوب">خوب</option>';
echo '<option value="متوسط">متوسط</option>';
echo '<option value="بد">بد</option>';
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ind" value="' . $amch["ind"] . '">'; //new line
echo '<br/>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="ارسال نظر شما"/>';echo'<hr/>';
echo'<hr/>';
echo'</div>';
echo "</form>\r\n";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple checkboxes, you want to know which checkbox you want to enable or disable.
A possible solution is to add an id to the textarea in the while loop and use the variable $i to make it unique, for example 'explain_1'.
Then you can also pass this $i to the javascript function for example 'enable_text(1)'' so that this function can get the textarea by id.

Maybe this will fix your issue:

change:

```
echo'<input type="checkbox" name=others onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" >شکایت دارم <br>';
echo'<textarea name="explain" id="explain" cols="" rows="" style="width:300 ;height:300">
</textarea>'.'<br/>';
```

to:

```
echo'<input type="checkbox" name=others onclick="enable_text(' . $i . ')" >شکایت دارم <br>';
echo'<textarea name="explain" id="explain_' . $i . '" cols="" rows="" style="width:300 ;height:300" disabled>
</textarea>'.'<br/>';
```

And then change

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function enable_text(status)
{
status=!status; 
    document.f1.explain.disabled = status;
}
//-->
</script>
```

to:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    <!--

    function enable_text(number) {
        var elm = document.getElementById('explain_' + number);
        elm.disabled = !elm.disabled;
    }
    //-->
</script>
```

Comment: seems I'm a bit late :)

Answer (score 0):

It is placing multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, which is why that fails.

Include the iterator `$i` in the `id` and the function:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name=others onclick="enable_text(this, $i)" >شکایت دارم <br/>';
echo '<textarea name="explain" id="explain$i" cols="" rows="" style="width:300 ;height:300"></textarea><br/>';
```

Alter the function to this:

```
function enable_text(element, i) {
    document.getElementById('explain' + i).disabled = !element.checked;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't scrolled far enough, saw there were more elements in between, stand by for edit...