# How to login to the Administrator page in PHP

Tags: php

here is my login page, after login in,common players goes to home.php. but i need if username and password was equal with a special player for example this user:

[image: admin]

then goes to adminpage.php

and code:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("home.php");
   }
}
      <!-- Form Code Start -->
<div id='fg_membersite'>
<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>ورود</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

<div class='short_explanation' dir="rtl">فیلدهای الزامی *</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container' dir="rtl">
    <label for='username' >:نام کاربری *</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container' dir="rtl">
    <label for='password' >:کلمه عبور *</label><br/>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='ورود' />

</div>
<!--
<div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>
</fieldset> -->
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[

    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("login");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

    frmvalidator.addValidation("username","req","لطفا نام کاربریتان را وارد نمایید");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("password","req","لطفا رمز عبورتان را وارد نمایید");

// ]]>
</script>
<p dir="rtl"><a href="confirmreg.php">تایید ثبت نام</a></p>
</div>
<!--
Form Code End (see html-form-guide.com for more info.)
-->
```

here is my functions in fg_membersite.php

```
function Login()
{

    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
    if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;

    return true;
}
```

this is users table (tablesite)

[image]

Comment: What is your problem? Did you try something?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem properly but all these answers can work. Did you try any?

Comment: @sinaza: can you answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860829/choose-a-name-from-drop-down-list-or-if-not-exit-can-write-in-text-box/33861097#33861097

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
     if($fgmembersite->Login()){
         if($fgmembersite->UserFullName() == "sajad"){
              $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("adminpage.php");
         }else{
              $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("home.php");
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Login()
{

    if(empty($_POST['username']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
    if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($username,$password))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if($username == "special_user_name")
    // redirect to adminlogin.php

    $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a few word of explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to and not averse to doing so I'd suggest adding a table to the db that contains various user roles and a new field in the table you shown above as a key to the new table. With the assigned role it is easier to vary which users get to see what content - ie: administrators get to see edit links, registered users get to see new pages etc.

```
create table `roles` (
    `id` tinyint(3) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `role` varchar(16) not null,
    primary key (`id`)
)
collate='utf8mb4_persian_ci' engine=innodb;

insert into `roles` (`id`, `role`) values
    (1, 'administrator'),
    (2, 'special guest'),
    (3, 'guest'),
    (4, 'public');

alter table `tablesite`
    add column `role` tinyint unsigned not null default '3' after `id_user`,
    add index `role` (`role`);

alter table `tablesite`
    add constraint `fk_usr_role` foreign key (`role`) references `roles` (`id`) on update cascade on delete cascade;
```